# Mule 4 long running httpRequest -http request that connects sap system which takes 10 minutes to give response

Tags: mule

in mule 4  have to trigger http request with post to sap system , sap system takes 10 minutes to give response, but DLB only keeps the http request for 5 minutes and after 5 minutes  getting http time out error, how to solve this issue pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the request to take less than 5 minutes. There is no way around it. Ask for less data or design an API that can process responses asynchronously.

That timeout is to prevent the DLB to run out of resources under load. Even 5 minutes can be too high depending on load.